# Add shape as background with fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to draw a shape as a background using fabric.js. I am trying to set `scalable` to false when creating the shape but it isn't working as expected.

I can’t select other shapes when `scalable` is set to false. Can someone tell me how can I do this?

The code I am using is below:

```
var pol = new fabric.Polygon([
                 {x: 200, y: 0},
              {x: 250, y: 50},
                {x: 250, y: 100},
               { x: 150, y: 100},
              {x: 150, y: 50} 
           ], 
         {
            left: 0,
             top: 0,
            scaleX: 2,
            scaleY: 2,
            fill: 'green'
        }
    );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set any shape as a background in *fabric.js* , using [**`setBackgroundImage`**](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#setBackgroundImage) method. This method won't affect other shapes and will resolve the object selection issue.

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var pol = new fabric.Polygon([
   { x: 200, y: 0 },
   { x: 250, y: 50 },
   { x: 250, y: 100 },
   { x: 150, y: 100 },
   { x: 150, y: 50 }],
{
   left: 0,
   top: 0,
   scaleX: 2,
   scaleY: 2,
   fill: 'green'
});

canvas.setBackgroundImage(pol);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {
    var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  
    // create a rectangle with a fill and a different color stroke
    var pol = new fabric.Polygon([
                 {x: 200, y: 0},
              {x: 250, y: 50},
                {x: 250, y: 100},
               { x: 150, y: 100},
              {x: 150, y: 50} 
           ], 
         {
            left: 0,
             top: 0,
            selectable:false,
            fill: 'green'
        }
    );
    pol.set({
    scaleX: canvas.width/pol.width,
    scaleY: canvas.height/pol.height,
    })
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(pol);
    canvas.renderAll();    
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

This one will fit to any canvas size, set scaleX and scaleY